# Unexpected result when converting decimal to fraction

Tags: javascript, math, decimal

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    return (b) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}
var dec2Frac = function (d) {
    var top = d.toString().replace(/\d+[.]/, '');
    var bot = Math.pow(10, top.length);
    if (d > 1) {
        top = +top + Math.floor(d) * bot;
    }
    var x = gcd(top, bot);
    var r1 = top / x;
    var r2 = bot / x;
    var frac =  r1 + "/" + r2;
    var parts = frac.split('/');
    var simpler = parts[0][0]+'/'+parts[1][0];
    return simpler;
};
```

If I input `640x960` = `0.66666666666667`

I'm expecting the result to be `2/3` as evident here: http://www.mindspring.com/~alanh/fracs.html

Instead this function returns `6/1`. Test here: http://jsbin.com/asoxud/1/

Comment: Why are you expecting `2/3` as result?  Your algorithm has nothing to do with proper rounding techniques such as continued fractions.

Comment: Some debugging technique can help: http://jsbin.com/asoxud/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to MvG's Answer,

I found this quite interesting and wanted to understand how floating points are stored and how to get back an fraction of a float to maybe do calculations with them.

It gave a bit of brainache trying to figure this out on my own, but as it made click, i came up with this `Fraction` function,

I don't know if this helps you or not, but

now that its written anyway , why not leave it here

```
function Fraction(n, d) {
    if ("number" !== typeof n)
        throw new TypeError("Excptected Parameter to be of type number");

    var strings = n.toString(2).split("."); //Split the number by its decimal point 

    if (strings.length > 1 && !d) { //No denominator given and n is a float

        var floats = [strings[1].substr(0, 27), strings[1].substr(27, 54)]; //Split into to parts 

        var int64 = [
            parseInt(floats[0], 2) << 1,
            parseInt(floats[1], 2) << 1
        ];

        var denominator = Math.pow(2, strings[1].length + 1); //
        var numerator = int64[0] * Math.pow(2, floats[1].length);

        numerator += int64[1];
        numerator += parseInt(strings[0], 2) * denominator;

        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
        this.reduce();

        this.approx = approx(n);

    } else if (strings.length < 2 && !d) { // If no denominator and n is an int 
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = 1;
    } else { //if n and d
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = d;
    }

    function approx(f, n) {
        n = n || 0;
        var fraction = new Fraction(1, 1);

        var float = Math.pow(f, -1);
        var rec = ~~float;
        var decimal = float - rec;

        if (float.toPrecision(Fraction.precision) == rec)
            return new Fraction(1, rec);
        var _fraction = approx(decimal, n + 1);

        fraction.denominator = rec * _fraction.denominator + _fraction.numerator;
        fraction.numerator = _fraction.denominator;

        return fraction;

    }

}

//The approx precision
Fraction.precision = 10;
Fraction.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;
};
Fraction.prototype.gcd = function () {
    return (function gcd(u, v) {
        return ((u > 0) ? gcd(v % u, u) : v);
    })(this.numerator, this.denominator);
};
Fraction.prototype.reduce = function () {
    var _gcd = this.gcd();
    this.numerator /= _gcd;
    this.denominator /= _gcd;
};

Fraction.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return this.numerator / this.denominator;
};




var f = new Fraction(0.3333); 
+ f; //0.3333333333
f.toString(); // 6004799502560181/18014398509481984 
+ f.approx //0.33333
+ f.approx.toString() //3333/10000

var g = new Fraction(2 / 3); 
+ g; //0.6666666666666666
g.toString(); //6004799503160661/9007199254740992
+ g.approx //0.6666666666666666
+ g.approx.toString() //2/3
```

Heres a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/awomam/1/edit) as well

Answer (score 0):

Your floating point numbers are approximations of the rational numbers you hope for. See e.g. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1468366) for details on this. The upshoot is: you can't hope to actually find a numerator and denominator which represent your original fraction.

If you want that fraction, you should have a look at [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). Each truncated continued fraction will represent the [best possible rational approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) for an arbitrary value. You can continue this until the error is sufficiently small.

[Here](http://www-m10.ma.tum.de/bin/view/Lehre/Bsp5_4) is a page visualizing this approximation. The text is in German, but the maths should be clear enough. [This page](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/ContinuedFraction/Decimal%20to%20Fraction.html) is in English but doesn't have as much visualization.